# Delete all files not modified in last ten days

Tags: java, last-modified, delete-file

I have a folder where I keep log files and I have a job scheduled to run each day to delete old logs.

What's a good way to delete old log files?

Currently, I loop through the directory to read files

```
File[] listOfFiles = srcFolder.listFiles(fileNameFilter); // this makes an array of files which match a filter I created
for(int i=listOfFiles.length-1; i>0; i--){ // leave at least one file

    // listOfFiles[i].lastModified() - in last ten days?
    if( what condition ?){
        try {
            listOfFiles[i].delete();
        } catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

I'm thinking

```
 if(listOfFiles[i].lastModified() < tenDaysAgoMS) // where tenDaysAgoMS is the milliseconds ten days ago, but how to implement?
```

Comment: I don't see why your proposed solution wouldn't work. Have you tried it?

Comment: No I wasn't sure how best to implement it, just compare today as (new Date()).getTime()?

Comment: No, I would so something like `long now = System.currentTimeMillis();`
And then just compare that value to the `lastModified()` value. if that's more than 10 days, then delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to subtract the last-modified property to the current time.
See [`Calendar.getTimeInMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()) and [`File.lastModified()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified()).

Then, you can convert days to milliseconds by multiplying them to `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24`.

1. `1000ms` = `1s`
2. `60s` = `1m`
3. `60m` = `1h`
4. `24h` = `1d`

---

```
long now = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
long oneDay = 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L;
long tenDays = 10L * oneDay;

File log = listOfFiles[i];
long diff = now - log.lastModified();
if (diff > tenDays) {
    log.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like

```
if( (System.currentTimeMillis() - listOfFiles[i].lastModified()) > 10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000){
}
```

Comment: +1 because you used all numbers seperated to make it clear what you're doing.

Comment: I like the solution, but I think the parentheses are off a little

Comment: Also, would it be more efficient to pull the calculation of time (10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) outside the if statement, since we know it will be constant?

Answer (score 1):

Use the tools at your disposal. It's much clearer than playing with milliseconds and stuff like that. I give an answer with Java's `Calendar` because I get that you shouldn't need any external library like Joda Time, since the task is quite easy. If you have Java 8, use the `java.time` API.

```
Calendar tenDaysAgo = Calendar.getInstance();
tenDaysAgo.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -10); // yeah, Calendar is really not a good API.

File[] listOfFiles = srcFolder.listFiles(fileNameFilter);
for(int i = listOfFiles.length - 1; i > 0; i--){ // leave at least one file
    File file = listOfFiles[i];
    Calendar fileDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    fileDate.setTime(new Date(file.lastModified()));
    if (fileDate.before(tenDaysAgo)) {
        try {
            file.delete();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle the error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use this early on, but I felt it was more cumbersome than the answers using system time and comparing that to a time span.

Comment: Cumbersome? You're speaking about 4-5 lines of code, which are rather fast. Ok, this will never beat the speed of computing it by hand, but since it's a script, do you really need to win the half millisecond gain for less readability?

Answer (score 1):

## More Precise

How specific is your requirements? The other answers are good enough for approximately ten days. But if you mean something more precise such as exactly the ten full days prior to today, then you need to use either the Joda-Time library or the new java.time package built into Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time).

Get the first moment of the day by calling `withTimeAtStartOfDay`. This is usually `00:00:00.000` but not always.

How important is time  zone. If omitted, you get the JVM’s current default time zone. Generally better to specify the desired time zone. Perhaps you want UTC for consistency.

## Joda-Time

Example code in Joda-Time 2.5.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ); // or DateTimeZone.UTC
DateTime now = DateTime.now( zone );
DateTime then = now.minusDays( 10 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
long millisSinceEpoch = then.getMillis();  // If needed to compare to files.
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this level of precision is not required (I believe) but I could be wrong.